# Using JSX without <script type="text/jsx"> tag?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a chrome extension, specifically the content script functionality which injects my js into a website.

Since I'm basically just working with a .js fil that gets injected, I am unable to make make this declaration which seems necessary for jsx to work.

```
  <script type="text/jsx">
  /**@jsx React.DOM*/
```

Is there any other way I can utilize JSX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since running the JSX transformation is slower than not running it, you probably want to just precompile the JSX (using the `jsx` binary provided by `react-tools`) when you distribute the extension. That said, if you include JSXTransformer.js then there's a `JSXTransformer.exec(...)` method which transforms and evals its argument.